# consul keeps looking for the dead server node

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, consul

I have consul cluster in production which is integrated with terraform, ansible,nomad,docker,vault. My consul keeps looking for the dead node which was part of initial setup even after removing entry from `peers.json` of the raft. Below is my consul log.

```
==> Starting Consul agent...
==> Starting Consul agent RPC...
==> Consul agent running!
         Node name: 'ip-10-10-2-49'
        Datacenter: 'us-east-1'
            Server: true (bootstrap: false)
       Client Addr: 0.0.0.0 (HTTP: 8500, HTTPS: -1, DNS: 8600, RPC: 8400)
      Cluster Addr: 10.10.2.49 (LAN: 8301, WAN: 8302)
    Gossip encrypt: false, RPC-TLS: false, TLS-Incoming: false
             Atlas: <disabled>

==> Log data will now stream in as it occurs:

    2017/01/24 13:52:59 [INFO] raft: Restored from snapshot 1596-4460452-1485234581011
    2017/01/24 13:52:59 [INFO] raft: Node at 10.10.2.49:8300 [Follower] entering Follower state
    2017/01/24 13:52:59 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: ip-10-10-2-49 10.10.2.49
    2017/01/24 13:52:59 [INFO] serf: Attempting re-join to previously known node: ip-10-0-1-206: 10.0.1.206:8301
    2017/01/24 13:52:59 [INFO] consul: adding LAN server ip-10-10-2-49 (Addr: 10.10.2.49:8300) (DC: us-east-1)
    2017/01/24 13:52:59 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: ip-10-10-4-149 10.10.4.149
    2017/01/24 13:52:59 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: ip-10-10-1-10 10.10.1.10
    2017/01/24 13:52:59 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: ip-10-0-3-119 10.0.3.119
    2017/01/24 13:52:59 [WARN] memberlist: Refuting an alive message
    2017/01/24 13:52:59 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: ip-10-10-3-84 10.10.3.84
    2017/01/24 13:52:59 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: ip-10-0-1-206 10.0.1.206
    2017/01/24 13:52:59 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: ip-10-10-1-252 10.10.1.252
    2017/01/24 13:52:59 [INFO] serf: Re-joined to previously known node: ip-10-0-1-206: 10.0.1.206:8301
    2017/01/24 13:52:59 [INFO] consul: adding LAN server ip-10-10-1-10 (Addr: 10.10.1.10:8300) (DC: us-east-1)
    2017/01/24 13:52:59 [INFO] consul: adding LAN server ip-10-10-3-84 (Addr: 10.10.3.84:8300) (DC: us-east-1)
    2017/01/24 13:52:59 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: ip-10-10-2-49.us-east-1 10.10.2.49
    2017/01/24 13:52:59 [INFO] consul: adding WAN server ip-10-10-2-49.us-east-1 (Addr: 10.10.2.49:8300) (DC: us-east-1)
    2017/01/24 13:52:59 [WARN] serf: Failed to re-join any previously known node
    2017/01/24 13:52:59 [INFO] agent: Joining cluster...
    2017/01/24 13:52:59 [ERR] agent: failed to sync remote state: No cluster leader
    2017/01/24 13:52:59 [INFO] agent: (LAN) joining: [consul-1.example-private.com consul-2.example-private.com consul-3.example-private.com]
    2017/01/24 13:52:59 [INFO] agent: (LAN) joined: 3 Err: <nil>
    2017/01/24 13:52:59 [INFO] agent: Join completed. Synced with 3 initial agents
    2017/01/24 13:53:01 [WARN] raft: Heartbeat timeout reached, starting election
    2017/01/24 13:53:01 [INFO] raft: Node at 10.10.2.49:8300 [Candidate] entering Candidate state
    2017/01/24 13:53:01 [INFO] raft: Election won. Tally: 3
    2017/01/24 13:53:01 [INFO] raft: Node at 10.10.2.49:8300 [Leader] entering Leader state
    2017/01/24 13:53:01 [INFO] consul: cluster leadership acquired
    2017/01/24 13:53:01 [INFO] consul: New leader elected: ip-10-10-2-49
    2017/01/24 13:53:01 [INFO] raft: pipelining replication to peer 10.10.3.84:8300
    2017/01/24 13:53:01 [INFO] raft: pipelining replication to peer 10.10.1.10:8300
    2017/01/24 13:53:01 [WARN] raft: Failed to contact 10.10.1.23:8300 in 501.633573ms
    2017/01/24 13:53:02 [INFO] agent: Synced node info
    2017/01/24 13:53:02 [WARN] raft: Failed to contact 10.10.1.23:8300 in 961.388392ms
    2017/01/24 13:53:02 [WARN] raft: Failed to contact 10.10.1.23:8300 in 1.42262185s
    2017/01/24 13:53:11 [ERR] raft: Failed to make RequestVote RPC to 10.10.1.23:8300: dial tcp 10.10.1.23:8300: i/o timeout
    2017/01/24 13:53:11 [ERR] raft: Failed to AppendEntries to 10.10.1.23:8300: dial tcp 10.10.1.23:8300: i/o timeout
    2017/01/24 13:53:11 [ERR] raft: Failed to heartbeat to 10.10.1.23:8300: dial tcp 10.10.1.23:8300: i/o timeout
```

I tried to remove the entry of dead node `10.10.1.23` from peers.json and started it all again but it keeps looking for same dead node. Can someone guide me how to kick out the dead node. I tried all the basic commands outlined in consul document to kick this particular node out however after the restart of service it starts appearing in logs.

Answer (score 1):

To remove a dead node that's still in the cluster state, you can call `consul force-leave <node name>` from a live node. This will put that node in the "left" state in the cluster, which is what should have happened if the node had left the cluster gracefully.